# Microchip MPLABX ADC simulation issue: ADC-W101: Selected channel is configured as digital IO

Tags: simulator, microchip, mplab, adc

I'm trying to simulate the following program with MPLAB X simulator, but the ADC seems not working. I have attached a stimulus file with '0303' values to the ADRESL register but I have no read and in the simulator console i got a warning "ADC-W101: Selected channel is configured as digital IO. The channel selected:0.". Moreover once set, the ADCON0 GO bit doesn't clear, even if the ADIF is triggered. The pic is a 16f88.
Is it a problem of the MPLAB X simulator? I've checked the limitations of MPLABX sim with the 16f88 but there is nothing about the ADC.

```
    processor   16f88
    include     <P16F88.INC>

    errorlevel  0, -302     ; suppress messages about bank selection

    __CONFIG    _CONFIG1, _WDT_OFF & _FOSC_INTOSCIO & _MCLR_ON & _LVP_OFF

    udata
LIGHT_SENS  res 2

TEMP_W      res 1
TEMP_STATUS res 1
TEMP_PCLATH res 1

FLAGS       res 1

TIME1       equ h'00000'
ADC         equ h'00001'

reset code 0x00

    pagesel main
    goto    main

isr code 0x04
_isr_entry:
    movwf   TEMP_W
    swapf   STATUS, W
    clrf    STATUS
    movwf   TEMP_STATUS
    movf    PCLATH, W
    movwf   TEMP_PCLATH
    clrf    PCLATH

_isr_test_tmr0:
    banksel INTCON
    btfss   INTCON, TMR0IF
    goto    _isr_test_adc

_tmr0_isr:
_tmr0_isr_entry:
    banksel TMR0
    movlw   d'100'
    movwf   TMR0

    bsf     FLAGS, TIME1

_tmr0_isr_exit:
    banksel INTCON
    bcf INTCON, TMR0IF

_isr_test_adc:
    banksel PIR1
    btfss   PIR1, ADIF
    goto    _isr_exit

_adc_isr:
_adc_isr_entry:
    banksel FLAGS
    bsf     FLAGS, ADC

_adc_isr_exit:
    banksel PIR1
    bcf     PIR1, ADIF

_isr_exit:
    movf    TEMP_PCLATH, W
    movwf   PCLATH
    swapf   TEMP_STATUS, W
    movwf   STATUS
    swapf   TEMP_W, F
    swapf   TEMP_W, W
    retfie

;===============================================================================
main code
main

_setup_oscillator:
    banksel OSCCON
    movlw   b'01100000'     ; 4 MHz Internal Oscillator Clock Speed
    movwf   OSCCON
    clrf    OSCTUNE         ; Center frequency

;===============================================================================
_setup_pin:

banksel PORTA
    clrf    PORTA           ; clears the latch on PORTA before configuring it
    banksel PORTB
    clrf    PORTB           ; clears the latch on PORTB before configuring it

_setup_tmr0:
    banksel TMR0
    movlw   d'100'
    movwf   TMR0
    banksel OPTION_REG
    movlw   b'11010101'     ; Prescaler is assigned to Timer0, rate 1:256, Timer mode
    movwf   OPTION_REG
    bsf     INTCON, TMR0IE  ; enables Timer0 Overflow Interrupt

_setup_adcs:
    banksel TRISA           ; set PORTA pin direction
    movlw   h'01'           ; RA0 is analog input
    movwf   TRISA

    banksel ANSEL           ; select analog pins
    movlw   h'01'           ; AN0 is analog I/O
    movwf   ANSEL

    banksel ADCON0          ; A/D channel selection
    movlw   b'10000000'     ; channel AN0 selected
    movwf   ADCON0

    banksel ADCON1          ; voltage reference, result justification, A/D clock
    movlw   b'10000000'     ; right just, Vdd/Vss ref
    movwf   ADCON1

    banksel ADCON0
    bsf     ADCON0, ADON

    banksel PIE1
    bsf     PIE1, ADIE
    banksel PIR1            ; enables A/DC interrupt
    bcf     PIR1, ADIF

    banksel INTCON
    bsf     INTCON, GIE     ; enables global interrupt
    bsf     INTCON, PEIE    ; enables peripheral interrupt

_setup_application:
    clrf    FLAGS

_main_loop:
    call    CheckAdc

_main_loop_exit:
    clrf    FLAGS
    goto    _main_loop

;===============================================================================
CheckAdc
_CheckAdc_entry:
    banksel FLAGS
    btfss   FLAGS, ADC          ; tests if ADC is ready
    goto    _CheckAdc_restart

    banksel ADRESL
    movf    ADRESL, W

    banksel LIGHT_SENS
    movwf   LIGHT_SENS

    banksel ADRESH
    movf    ADRESH, W

    banksel LIGHT_SENS
    movwf   LIGHT_SENS+1

_CheckAdc_restart:
    banksel FLAGS
    btfss   FLAGS, TIME1        ; tests if 1ms timer run out
    goto    _CheckAdc_exit

    banksel ADCON0
    btfss   ADCON0, GO
    bsf     ADCON0, GO

_CheckAdc_exit:

    return

    end                         ; End Of Program
```